# Java autogenerate directories if exists

Tags: java

I'm trying to check if a directory exists, if that happens I want to give it another number, for example, if "folderX" exists I want to create a new one called "FolderX1", at the moment I'm just able to do this once since I have it on an  if/else statement like this:

```
    File fa = new File(folder);

    if(!fa.exists()){
        this.folder = folder;
    }else{
        this.folder = folder+=1;

     }
```

I want do this recursively, If the program detects that "folderX" exists it should jump and check the others (folderX,FolderX1,FolderX2, etc) until it finds one that can be created but i don't know how to do it.

Comment: Use a while loop around the `if`.

Comment: @ Tichodroma That would create an infinite loop i fear...

Comment: I think you should learn a bit about [apache camel](http://camel.apache.org/) for easiest way

Comment: @freak Apache Camel is a little bit of overkill for creating folders.

Comment: The only way this might happen is if you have `Integer.MIN_VALUE` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` folders...which is an awful lot folders.  In which case you could put an upper limit to your index and break the loop (and throw an exception) if you reach it...

Comment: @freak Thanks, but it needs to be done with java 100%

Comment: @Tichodroma please explain what do you mean?

Comment: @eon Apache camel is also a pure Java API , Do you want to say that You want to do this without using any 3rd party API?

Comment: @freak Yup, can't use API's

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, you need some kind of loop that can determine if the incrementing folder still exists...

```
File makeMe = new File(folder);
int index = 0;
String master = folder;
while (makeMe.exists()) {
    folder = master + (++index);
    makeMe = new File(folder);
}
```

If you're worried about creating an infinite loop, you could place a maximum range...

```
int maxRange = 100;

File makeMe = new File(folder);
int index = 0;
String master = folder;
while (makeMe.exists() && index < maxRange) {
    makeMe = new File(master + (++index));
}

if (index > maxRange) { // || makeMe.exists()
    throw new IOException("Could not find free directory");
} else {
    // All happy unicorns...
}
```

Comment: That seems like an infinite loop, isn't it?

Comment: Only if there are `Integer.MAX_VALUE` folders within the target location.  Are you intending to create that many directories?

Comment: @eon providing `maxRange` is the only way to break this loop otherwise there is no logic to break the loop in your scenario

Comment: Also an ".endwith()" numbes or change the folder name each time since "folder" has always the same name.

Comment: @eon Sorry, miss the point of that. I use a `masterFolder` name as a base and generate a new name using `masterFolder` and the `index`.  You don't HAVE quite do it this way, it was just what I hacked together...

Answer (score 3):

```
String folderPrefix = "folder";
int folderSuffix = 0;
File fa = new File(folderPrefix + folderSuffix);

while (fa.exists()) {
  fa = new File(folderPrefix + folderSuffix++);
}
```