# screenshot saving as autogenerated file name

Tags: java, filenames

I made a button to take the screenshot and save into Pictures folder. I set it as being saved under the name capture.jpeg but I wanted it to be saved as such as cafe001.jpeg, cafe002.jpeg like this. Also would you please let me know how I can save it as time format.jpeg ?
Thank you for your help in advance

```
container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);
        Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.captureButton);
        captureButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            container.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap captureView = container.getDrawingCache();
            FileOutputStream fos;
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString() + "capture.jpeg");
                captureView.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Captured under Pictures drectory", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically have a couple of choices...

### You could...

List all the files in the directory and simple increment the file count by 1 and use that...

```
File[] files = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString()).
    listFiles(new FileFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File pathname) {
            String name = pathname.getName();
            return pathname.isFile() && name.toLowerCase().startsWith("capture") && name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpeg");
        }
});

int fileCount = files.length();

fos = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString() + 
    "capture" + fileCount + ".jpeg");
```

This, of course, doesn't take into account if a file with the same index exists...

### You could...

List all the files, sort them, grab the last one, find it's index value and increment that...

Something like...

```
File[] files = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString()).
    listFiles(new FileFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File pathname) {
            String name = pathname.getName();
            return pathname.isFile() && name.toLowerCase().startsWith("capture") && name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpeg");
        }
});

Arrays.sort(files);
File last = files[files.length - 1];

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(last.getName());

int index = 1;
if (matcher.find()) {
    String match = matcher.group();
    index = Integer.parseInt(match) + 1;
}

String fileName = "capture" + index + ".jpeg"
```

### You could...

Simply create a loop and loop until you find an empty index position...for example see, [Java autogenerate directories if exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17081038/java-autogenerate-directories-if-exists/17081082#17081082)

Answer (score 0):

To save as another name just change the string `"capture.jpeg"`

If you want to have it as cafeXXX.jpeg (where XXX is a number) then you could do something like this (this method could potentially cause number overlaps however if files are deleted):

```
int count = 1;
File picturesDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
File[] content = picturesDir.listFiles();
for (File f: content)
{
    if (f.getName().matches("cafe\\d+\\.jpeg"))
        count++;
}
//... your other code
// if leading zeros important then add formatting code to the count
fos = new FileOutputStream(picturesDir.toString() + "cafe"+count+".jpeg");
```

If you want a timeformat just use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) changing the format String as required (as only going to day will mean you will only get time format per day)

```
String timeFileName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date())
//...other code
fos = new FileOutputStream(picturesDir.toString() + timeFileName+".jpeg");
```