# Get filename with date and trailing counter

Tags: java, filenames

I need to frame a file name as `name_<date>_N`, where N is a counter for the number of similar files.

```
String fileName = "name";
String fileNameWithDate = fileName + "_"+ new SimpleDateFormat("MMM_dd_yyyy").format(cal.getTime());
```

If I try to download more times for a given date, the count should be incremented by 1; for example, `name_Dec_10_2015_N`. How do I get filename with date and incremented by 1?

Comment: `File#exists` and `File#listFiles(FileFilter)` will be of help to you here...

Comment: i dont understand. Can you provide with example?

Comment: You will want to try and list all the files which match the prefix you are using.  When there are more then one, you will want to find out how many and increment the number...

Comment: would be helpful if there is any code example

Comment: You mean something like [this previous example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324203/screenshot-saving-as-autogenerated-file-name/18324758#18324758)

Comment: No, it is different. if i download more time for a given date, then only the count will be bumped by 1

Comment: How is it different?  You have a filename, you want to find out if there are any with the existing name and if so, find out how many there are and increment the result.  From my persepetive, its the same thing

Comment: @ankitf Please have a look if the posted answer could already help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MadProgrammer already wrote you need to do it in following steps

- get a list of all files matching your pattern
- find the file with the highest counter
- created the file name for the increased counter

Here is short snippet which you can use as a starting point (the handling of edge cases, like: no file found, etc., are intentionally omited and part of your own work)

```
public class IncreaseCounter {

    static final SimpleDateFormat FILE_DATE = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM_dd_yyyy");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // filter files which matches the given pattern
        FilenameFilter fileNameFilter = new FilenameFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                return name.matches("^name_..._.._.....*\\.txt");
            }
        };

        // needed to sort the file list based on the file counter
        Comparator<File> sortByCounter = new Comparator<File>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(File file1, File file2) {
                return getFileCounter(file1.getName()) - getFileCounter(file2.getName());
            }
        };

        String filesLocation = "resources/";
        int highestCounter = 0;

        // read the files matching the filter
        File[] listFiles = new File(filesLocation).listFiles(fileNameFilter);
        List<File> files = Arrays.asList(listFiles);

        // sort the files by their file counter
        Collections.sort(files, sortByCounter);

        // get the highest counter
        String fileWithHighestCounter = files.get(files.size() - 1).getName();
        highestCounter = getFileCounter(fileWithHighestCounter);

        String nextFileName = String.format("name_%s_%d.txt",
                FILE_DATE.format(new Date()), 
                highestCounter + 1
        );

        System.out.println("nextFileName = " + nextFileName);
    }

    /**
     * Extract the file counter.
     * @param fileName the file name
     * @return 0 - if the file has no counter, otherwise the counter value
     */
    static int getFileCounter(String fileName) {
        String namePatternWithCounter = "^name_..._.._...._*(.*)\\.txt";
        String counterString = fileName.replaceAll(namePatternWithCounter, "$1");
        if (counterString.isEmpty()) {
            return 0;
        }
        return Integer.parseInt(counterString);
    }
}
```