# How to create a new file with additional incrementing number when file already exists?

Tags: java, file

I have a small piece of code

```
String fileName = "test.txt"
Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
File f = null;
if (Files.exists(path)) {
    LOGGER.warn("File allready exists!");
    f = new File("COPYOF-" + fileName);
} else {
    f = new File(fileName);
}
```

It works, but it doesn't do what I want it to do...

I would like to do it the "proper" way.

On first download the file should be named `test.txt`. On second - `test(1).txt`. On third: `test(2).txt` etc.

Currently it is downloading it as `test.txt` and the second time it is named `COPYOF-test.txt` and on the third attempt it is just overriding the `COPYOF-test.txt` file.

I'm looking for a proper way to implement this solution but I have no idea how to do it...

Comment: can you add some more code, like the function where you are calling it .

Comment: Have a look to the answer in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294470/get-filename-with-date-and-trailing-counter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working Code:

```
String fileName = "test.txt";

String extension = "";
String name = "";

int idxOfDot = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');   //Get the last index of . to separate extension
extension = fileName.substring(idxOfDot + 1);
name = fileName.substring(0, idxOfDot);

Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
int counter = 1;
File f = null;
while(Files.exists(path)){
    fileName = name+"("+counter+")."+extension;
    path = Paths.get(fileName);
    counter++;
}
f = new File(fileName);
```

**Explanation:**

1. Firstly separate `extension` and `file name without extension` and set `counter=1` then check if this file exists or not. If exists go to step 2 otherwise got to step 3.
2. If file exists then generate new name with `file name without extension`+`(`+`counter`+`)`+`extension` and check this file exists or not. If exists then repeat this step with increment `counter`.
3. Here create file with latest generated file name.

Answer (score 1):

```
String fileName = "test.txt";
String[] parts = fileName.split(".");
Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
File f = null;
int i = 1;
while (Files.exists(path)) {
    LOGGER.warn("File allready exists!");
    i++;
    path = Paths.get(parts[0] + "(" + i + ")" + parts[1]);
} 
f = new File(parts[0] + "(" + i + ")" + parts[1]);
```

PS : I'dd add a specific method just to incrementFileName(String fileName). It would more clean code. And you will be able to check specific cases (file with dots, montextpartie(1)et(3).txt...Etc

Comment: String[] parts = fileName.split("."); would allow a variable filename... and then f = new File(parts[0] + "(" + i + ")"+parts[1]);

Comment: @Margu Unless the file has more than one `.`, like `test.tar.gz`; in this case, it would "forget" part of the file name/extension.

Comment: @tobias_k that's true, better is the answer from Zaman which is also the accepted answer now.

Answer (score 0):

To generalize on Fundhor's answer:

```
String fileName = "test.txt";
ArrayList<String> fileNameArray = Arrays.asList(fileName.split("\\."));
String fileExtension = fileNameArray.remove(fileNameArray.size() - 1);
StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
while (fileNameArray.size() != 0) {
   strBuilder.append(fileNameArray.remove(0));
}
String fileNameWithoutExtension = strBuilder.toString();
Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
File f = null;
int i = 1;
while(Files.exists(path)) {
    LOGGER.warn("File already exists!");
    fileName = fileNameWithoutExtension + "(" + i + ")" + "." + fileExtension;
    path = Paths.get(fileName);
}
f = new File(fileName);
```

My answer also allows filenames with periods in their names, for example `part1.part2.extension`