# Java - renaming output file if name already exists with an increment, taking into account existing increments

Tags: java, regex, filenames, increment

building an Android app i came across the need to do some file copying. I would like a way to get new filenames in the event of a filename allready being used by adding a "(increment)" string in the filename. for example

```
text.txt ---> text(1).txt
```

The algorith should account for the following

1) if `text.txt` exists the new file name should `NEVER` be `text.txt(1)`

2) if `text(1).txt` exists then new filename should be `text(2).txt` not `text(1)(1).txt`

3) if `text(1)foo.txt` exists the new filename should be `text(1)foo(1).txt`

I've allready done the first but I'm having difficulties with the second. Regular expressions is not my strong suit!(It's not mandatory to use Regex. every approach is welcome) Some help ?

ANSWER:

combining my original code and one of the answers here I ended up with this which works very well for me in all cases regardless of file having an extension or not:

```
public static File getFinalNewDestinationFile(File destinationFolder, File fileToCopy){

    String destFolderPath = destinationFolder.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator;
    File newFile = new File(destFolderPath + fileToCopy.getName());
    String filename=fileToCopy.getName();
    String nameWithoutExtentionOrIncrement;
    String extension = getFileExtension(filename); 

    if(extension!=null){
        extension="."+extension;
        int extInd = filename.lastIndexOf(extension);
        nameWithoutExtentionOrIncrement = new StringBuilder(filename).replace(extInd, extInd+extension.length(),"").toString();
    }
    else{ 
        extension=""; 
        nameWithoutExtentionOrIncrement = filename;
    }

    int c=0;
    int indexOfClose = nameWithoutExtentionOrIncrement.lastIndexOf(")");
    int indexOfOpen = nameWithoutExtentionOrIncrement.lastIndexOf("(");

    if(indexOfClose!=-1 && indexOfClose!=-1 && indexOfClose==nameWithoutExtentionOrIncrement.length()-1 && indexOfClose > indexOfOpen && indexOfOpen!=0){
        String possibleNumber = nameWithoutExtentionOrIncrement.substring(indexOfOpen+1, indexOfClose);
        try{
            c = Integer.parseInt(possibleNumber);
            nameWithoutExtentionOrIncrement=nameWithoutExtentionOrIncrement.substring(0, indexOfOpen);
        }catch(Exception e){c=0;}
    } 

    while(newFile.exists()){
        c++; 
        String path = destFolderPath + nameWithoutExtentionOrIncrement +"(" + Integer.toString(c) + ")" + extension;
        newFile = new File(path);
    }
    return newFile;
}



    public static String getFileExtension(String filename) {
        if (filename == null) {  return null; }
        int lastUnixPos = filename.lastIndexOf('/');
        int lastWindowsPos = filename.lastIndexOf('\\');
        int indexOfLastSeparator = Math.max(lastUnixPos, lastWindowsPos);
        int extensionPos = filename.lastIndexOf('.');
        int lastSeparator = indexOfLastSeparator;
        int indexOfExtension = lastSeparator > extensionPos ? -1 : extensionPos;
        int index = indexOfExtension;
        if (index == -1) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return filename.substring(index + 1).toLowerCase();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have to use regex? It seems that you could do it more easily otherwise..

Comment: No it's not mandatory...I just figured that ti would be more efficient that way. every approach is welcome !

Comment: You cannot increment numbers in regex.

Comment: @noob But you can use regex to extract the part you need to increment, and the parts you need to leave unchanged.

Comment: You should also account for `filename_with_no_extension`.

Comment: @AJNeufeld: I was hoping this to cross OP's mind.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a new file with additional incrementing number when file already exists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33232304/how-to-create-a-new-file-with-additional-incrementing-number-when-file-already-e)

Comment: This question has been asked many times in SO. Somehow no one marks it as duplicate?

Comment: The possible duplicate doesn't take into account an existing increment.

Comment: Your edit which adds the "ANSWER:" section to your question fails your third test: `text(1)foo.txt` will become `text(2).txt`, not `text(1)foo(1).txt` as required.

Comment: you are right...i didn't see that. thanx for pointing that out !

Comment: I edited it so now it's working in that case too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using one regex pattern:

```
final static Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(.*?)(?:\\((\\d+)\\))?(\\.[^.]*)?");

String getNewName(String filename) {
    if (fileExists(filename)) {
        Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(filename);
        if (m.matches()) {
            String prefix = m.group(1);
            String last = m.group(2);
            String suffix = m.group(3);
            if (suffix == null) suffix = "";

            int count = last != null ? Integer.parseInt(last) : 0;

            do {
                count++;
                filename = prefix + "(" + count + ")" + suffix;
            } while (fileExists(filename));
        }
    }
    return filename;
}
```

The regex pattern explanation:

- `(.*?)` a non greedy "match everything" starting at the beginning
- `(?:\\((\\d+)\\))?` a number in parenthesis (optional)

  - `(?:____________)` - is a non capturing group
  - `___\\(______\\)_` - matches `(` and `)`
  - `______(\\d+)____` - matches and captures the one or more digits
- `(\\.[^.]+)?` a dot followed by anything but a dot (optional)

Comment: very elegant and quick way. The only downside is that if a file ends with "." the increment is added after the ".". example "foo."-->"foo.(1)"  adding an extension where previously there weren't.

Comment: @Anonymous Change the end of the regex from `(\\.[^.]+)?` to `(\\.[^.]*)?` and "foo." will become "foo(1)."

Answer (score 1):

I assume a couple of things:

1) A method called fileExists(String fileName) is available. It returns true if a file with the specified name is already present in the file system.

2) There is a constant called FILE_NAME which in your example case is equal to "text".

```
if (!fileExists(FILE_NAME)) {
    //create file with FILE_NAME.txt as name
}

int availableIndex = 1;
while (true) {
    if (!fileExists(currentName)) {
        //create file with FILE_NAME(availableIndex).txt
        break;
    }
    availableIndex++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
    String fileName;
    File file = new File(fileName);

    if(file.exists()) {
        int dot = fileName.lastIndexOf('.'), open = fileName.lastIndexOf('('), incr;
        boolean validNum = false;

        if(fileName.charAt(dot-1) == ')' && open != -1){
            String n = fileName.substring(open+1, dot-1);
            try {
                incr = Integer.parseInt(n);
                validNum = true;
            } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                validNum = false;
            }
        }

        if(validNum) {
            String pre = fileName.substring(0, open+1), post = fileName.substring(0, dot-1);
            while(new File(pre + ++incr + post).exists());
            fileName = pre + incr + post;
        } else {
            fileName = fileName.substring(0, dot) + "(1)" + fileName.substring(dot); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure about Android but since its a Java program, you may be able to create File object of the directory in which you want to write. 
Once you have this you can see the list of file names already present inside it and other related information. Then you can decide the file name as per your above logic.

```
File dir = new File("<dir-path>");
if(dir.isDirectory()){
        String[] files = dir.list();
        for(String fileName : files){
            <logic for finding filename>
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If all filenames have an extenstion you could do something like this (just an example you will have to change it to work in your case):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String test  = "test(1)foo.txt";
    String test1 = "test(1)foo(1).txt";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((?<=\\()\\d+(?=\\)\\.))");

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
    String fileOutput = "";
    String temp = null;
    int newInt = -1;
    while(matcher.find())
    {
        temp = matcher.group(0);
    }
    if(temp != null)
    {
        newInt = Integer.parseInt(temp);
        newInt++;
        fileOutput = test.replaceAll("\\(\\d+\\)(?=\\.(?!.*\\.))", "(" + newInt + ")");
    }
    else
    {
        fileOutput = test;
    }
    System.out.println(fileOutput);
    matcher = pattern.matcher(test1);
    fileOutput = "";
    temp = null;
    while(matcher.find())
    {
        temp = matcher.group(0);
    }
    if(temp != null)
    {
        newInt = Integer.parseInt(temp);
        newInt++;
        fileOutput = test1.replaceAll("\\(\\d+\\)(?=\\.(?!.*\\.))", "(" + newInt + ")");
    }
    else
    {
        fileOutput = test1;
    }
    System.out.println(fileOutput);
}
```

Output:

> test(1)foo.txt
>
> test(1)foo(2).txt

This uses regex to look for a number in the `()` right before the last `.`.

**Update**

`replaceAll()` changed to handle case where there is a `.` after the first `(1)` in `test(1).foo(1).txt`.