# Java Create File sequence, start from 01 for each new date and increase depending on total file per day

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I am doing a project and it requires to create file sequential.

Is it possible to create File sequence, starting from 1 for each new date and increase depending on total file per day?

Something like:

Today:01.txt, 02.txt, 03.txt

Tommorow: 01.txt, 02.txt, 03.txt .....

I have no idea how to start.

Comment: It is a little bit unclear what you want to do. Something like:
today: 01.txt, tomorrow: 02.txt, ... ? Meaning one per day? Or something other because the "total file per day" seems to contradict it.

Comment: you can store your counter/sequence variable in  database , then just : **fetch `--> ` Use `-->` Increment `-->` Store Back**

Comment: Hi Casey, I'm sorry i'm not define my question clearly .......What i want is 
eg. 
today 01.txt, next create 02.txt
tomorrow 01.txt, next 02.txt, 03.txt

per day might can up to 50.txt
second day will start from 01 again~~ Thanks

Comment: Hi Neeraj, do we have other way but try not touch on database? Btw this is a good idea..

Comment: You mean something [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324203/screenshot-saving-as-autogenerated-file-name/18324758#18324758)

Comment: Hi guys, Thanks for the all ideas, the problem was solved. I'm using Neeraj's idea. Store the sequence variable in database, and it work very well. Thanks