# Simplest way to name incoming files in order

Tags: java

I am having project in which I receive number of images from client and want store it in server by names in order such as 0.jpg, 1.jpg, 2.jpg.....

What is most efficient way to do that?

I tried using string formatting but its not working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That would depend. Are you getting all the files in single batch or are they coming at random times? How are your coving the files, through a web service or via sockets?

Comment: What do you mean by "string formatting is not working"?  Please show us what you tried.

Comment: You could do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324203/screenshot-saving-as-autogenerated-file-name/18324758#18324758) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17081038/java-autogenerate-directories-if-exists/17081082#17081082)

Comment: "I tried using string formatting but its not working." - please post your code so that people have something that they can help you with. Right now you're just asking for 'the codez' which is considered far too broad on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a number to name files you can have several parts in the file name. It will be useful to know something about the file just by looking at name. It can be without using database quite easily.

For example following is the code to generate unique names for a file, without intervention of Database.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class TestCode {
    static final AtomicInteger sequence = new AtomicInteger();
    static final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD:mm:ss:SSS");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = getUniqueName();
        System.out.println(name);
    }
    private static String getUniqueName() {
        String dateStr = sdf.format(new Date());
        String name = dateStr + "_" + sequence.incrementAndGet() + "_" + UUID.randomUUID() + ".jpg";
        return name;
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
2016-01-01:51:27:281_1_de653366-6847-47b6-9df0-13bb359c2459.jpg
```

This name tells us on which date and time was file saved and it uses `UUID` to keep names unique and an `AtomiInteger`(thread safety) to keep files created in the same moment have different sequential names.

Even if your AtomicIntege were to reset to zero on server restart, date and time would be different and file ordering would still be well defined.

Comment: Solution looks pretty impressive. Even though I am not using any threaded operation at receiver side and have no idea what atomic integer is, I will definitely check it out. Thank you for quick response. You da man!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a counter to automatically increment filenames.

```
while (true)
{
    int counter = 0;
    String automaticFilename = String.valueOf(counter);

    boolean exist = new File("path/to/".concat(automaticFilename).concat(".jpg")).isFile();

    if (exist)
    {
        counter++;
        continue;
    } else
    {
        // Create file etc.
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! Nice and simple solution!

Comment: Glad to be able to help!

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to store the current index in a persistent store (for example DB). When you a get new file from client

- Get current index, increment it by 1 and store it back
- Store the file with name as index.

Make sure that your persistent store supports concurrent access from multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this (not real java):

```
int fileNumber = 0
for(int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++){
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileNumber + ".jpg");
    for byte : image.getBytes(){
        fos.write(byte);
    }
    fos.close();
    fileNumber++;
}
```

(images are your images, I am not sure if there is a getBytes method)

Comment: Simple yet good solution! Thank you